# Push command in Javascript won't create the correct multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

I'm attempting to generate 10 random numbers 3 times and capture the hi, the lo, and last in every 10 number batch.  I create an array of the hi/lo/last that gets pushed into another array so I can keep track of the numbers.  Unfortunately the push command below seems to be only adding the last hi/lo/last 3 times, instead of each hi/lo/last. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Also, I clearly am not an expert programmer having worked mostly with VBA in excel where I could step through a program.  Is there any way to do that in Sublime with Javascript?  I'm working in a windows environment, using Sublime Text 2, with a Node build for Javascript.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
var price; 
var hiPrice; 
var loPrice;
var intervalPrices = []
var initialPrices = [];
var rows = 3;
var columns = 3;

var randomPrices = function(){
    price = 1
    hiPrice = price
    loPrice = price
    for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
        price = Math.round((price+(Math.random()*2-1)/1000)*100000)/100000
        priceIs()
        if (i%10 == 0){
            intervalPrices[0] = hiPrice
            intervalPrices[1] = loPrice
            intervalPrices[2] = price
            initialPrices.push(intervalPrices)
    hiPrice = price
    loPrice = price
        }
    }       
}

var priceIs = function(){
    if (price >= hiPrice) {
        hiPrice = price 
    }
    if (price < loPrice) {
        loPrice = price 
    }
 }

 randomPrices()
 console.log(initialPrices)
```

Comment: Basically you want to have different values in 3 of this arrays right? it is showing same in your current code

Answer (score 0):

Try making separate object or make it clone instead of original object.

```
initialPrices.push([intervalPrices[0], intervalPrices[1], intervalPrices[2]])
```

Now

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(initialPrices))
[[1.00092,0.99835,0.99906],[0.99906,0.99758,0.99762],[0.99907,0.99734,0.99907]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a prob of variable **reference** whenever you edit `intervalPrices` it will override prev value of `intervalPrices`. Pushing same variable with different value will not preserve the value already pushed to the array as every element of that array points to the same `intervalPrices` variable.

your updated code - read comment for better understanding

```
var randomPrices = function(){
    price = 1
    hiPrice = price
    loPrice = price
    for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
        //create a new Object
        var obj = {};
        price = Math.round((price+(Math.random()*2-1)/1000)*100000)/100000
        priceIs()
        if (i%10 == 0){
            //assing new values to the Object
            obj[0] = hiPrice
            obj[1] = loPrice
            obj[2] = price
            initialPrices.push(obj)
            hiPrice = price
            loPrice = price
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same variable name to build the array you're trying to push is causing you your issues.  Try this instead:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
    price = Math.round((price+(Math.random()*2-1)/1000)*100000)/100000;
    priceIs();
    if (i%10 == 0){
        initialPrices.push([hiPrice,loPrice,price]);
        hiPrice = 1;
        loPrice = 1;
    }
}
```

I also set hiPrice and loPrice back to 1 rather than the random number that was generated.